# The parts of the skeleton system or the parts of skeleton system?

Tags: articles, definite-article

When I'm talking generally about the skeleton, not about a specific skeleton, do I need to add the article "the" in following context?

This is a title in presentation which I'm writing about the skeleton system.

> "The parts of (**the**?) skeleton system"

Comment: Yes, since you are referring to a specific item (the system). This question needs more details as to why you are unclear. Article use in general? In your first sentence you left out necessary articles, too.

Comment: We need a little more context to be able to help. A skeleton system usually means a basic system of some type - no frills - figuratively, 'bare bones'. The skeletal system is the better term if you are referring to the anatomical skeleton

Comment: Thank you for your comment. AI realy wrote all what I know about. If you have specific questions, please let me know them, and I will anser.

Comment: People say *the skeletal system* much more often than *the skeleton system*.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**If** it is the **title,** enjoy the *liberty*! Said that, you may simply *omit* the article and it'll be okay. [Titles/Headlines often drop articles.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese)

### The Parts of Skeleton System

Or, even...

### Parts of Skeleton System

as **'Titles'** are okay.

---

What are you trying to refer as 'skeleton system'? Some chapter in software engineering or human bones? While 'skeleton system' is more common in software engineering, 'skeletal system' is more frequently used to denote human bone structure.

Comment: Headlines and tweets (formerly  telegrams) drop articles *to save room*. Academic papers and names of presentations do not.

Comment: It's a *title* in the **presentation**, maybe Powerpoint? Who knows? And, I'm a doctor! @User1

Comment: title of a presentation = name of a presentation. your answer is just wrong